# Problems on downloading html page through NSData

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I am currently trying to download the html code of a page for an app I am working on. For some reason when I try to download the code through

`NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=%@,@"Tracking#"]]];`

I dont get the right HTML code however. When I set up the same load request through a `UIWebView` have it load then then get the HTML code from `stringByEvauluatingJavaScript:@"document.body.innerhtml"` I do get the right one.

My question is, how do I make the `dataWithContentsOfURL` work and get the right code?

Comment: You should consider using the [Official FedEX Developer API](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/index.html), it'll make your data much easier to work with.

Comment: I will look into it as i probably will make things easier. I also believe they make it overly complex for what it is. However I have run into this problem before on things that don't have an API and finaly decided to post the question.

Comment: That's not what `NSURLConnection` should used for. `NSURLConnection` should used for things like download of a document, download of images, make requests to webservices etc. It's not to be used to get html from a website that's why it will not download the website html but it will load it in a `UIWebView` which is what a `UIWebView` is for.

Comment: `NSURLConnection` is not even being used. Why is it in the title?

Comment: Did you check and compare the actual requests sent (headers)?

Comment: I tried using NSURLConnection sendAsync and it did the same thing as dataWithContentsOfURL:.  I did check the headers they were the same.

Comment: @rmaddy I have a feeling that there is a lack of information here.

Comment: @Popeye i can post the whole code and the results if you so choose.  I was trying to condense it as i thought it was a simple question and all that was need was what i posted.